# Foundation for Apps with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, web-applications, zurb-foundation-apps

Has anyone been able to successfully to get Foundation for Apps to work with Rails. I have followed the instructions via the Foundation website but can't even get a simple module to work with Off Canvas Menu

```
!!!
%html{:lang => "en"}
  %head
    %meta{:content => "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}/
    %meta{:charset => "utf-8"}/
    %meta{:content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0", :name => "viewport"}/
    %title= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Bean'n'Gone"
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    %script{:src => "http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/zurb/foundation-apps-1.1.0.js"}
    %script{:src => "http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/zurb/foundation-apps-1.1.0.min.js"}
    %script{:src => "http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/zurb/foundation-apps-templates-1.1.0.js"}
    %script{:src => "http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/zurb/foundation-apps-templates-1.1.0.min.js"}

    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    %zf-offcanvas#menu{:position => "left"}
      %a.close-button{"zf-close" => ""} ×
    %a.button{"zf-open" => "menu"} Open Off-canvas
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Foundation for Apps, but for Angular, you must declare that your app is an Angular app in the HTML tag.

For example:

```
<html ng-app="exampleApp">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Or, if you can't change the html tag, you can bootstrap after with: angular.bootstrap(document, ['exampleApp']);

Comment: Cheers it appeared that the Angular wasn't detecting the code because I hadn't declared the app